# Python, Keeping a dynamically named file open in a large modular program

Tags: python, file, dynamic, io, modular

I am trying to create a logfile for a large modular program. The name is dynamically produced with a timestamp and I can't think of a good way to pass the open filename other than to make it a global variable:

```
import time

def CreateLogFile():
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    global LogFile
    filenamestring = timestr + 'LogFile.txt'
    LogFile = open('PrintLogs/' + filenamestring, 'w')

CreateLogFile()
```

This isn't working well and I was wondering if anyone had a better suggestion. Thanks

Comment: You could wrap it all into a class to avoid the globals. Then you can pass around an instance of the class to the modules which need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your own logging module:

```
import mylogger

log_file_handle = mylogger.get_log()
```

The `get` method can (should) handle all the logic of creating a new logfile if you haven't made one yet, or returning a handle to the already-created-this-session one.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the logger module existed